# Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Unable to launch Edge driver i get below mentioned error and code i used is below. Please help

> Jun 28, 2017 10:09:52 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess
>   checkForError SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>   Process exited with an error: -1073741515 (Exit value: -1073741515)
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version:
>   '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
>   'ROHIT', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65' Driver info:
>   driver.version: EdgeDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:150)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:139)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:96)   at
>   TestNG_Check.Edge.main(Edge.java:14) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
>   for [http://localhost:14772/status] to be available after 20003 ms    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)
>     ... 10 more Caused by:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
>     ... 12 more

```
package TestNG_Check;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class Edge {

    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","E://NewSelenium//Edgedriver//MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        //create Edge instance
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was issue with Driver version of MicrosoftEdge. Sovled.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to either your Edge driver doesn't started due to some reason or the localhost hostname is not accesible.

Please read [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821461/selenium-chrome-browser-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waitin/52824533#52824533) for simmilar debugging steps for ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - update on 4/2/2021

I met this time out issue and resolve it by adding :  `options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");`

Samples with C#:

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
                options.UseChromium = true;
                options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
                driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```