# Selenium Chrome Browser org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class Dem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver;
    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Jim\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.close();
    }
}
```

Selenium webdriver and Chrome driver are the ***latest versions***

Selenium webdriver :3.14.0

chromedriver: 2.42

java:1.8.0_181

**And this is the error after running the code. Google chrome doesn't launch at all.**

> **SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741792 (Exit value: -1073741792) Exception in
>   thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out
>   waiting for driver server to start.** Build info: version: '3.14.0',
>   revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z' Driver info:
>   driver.version: ChromeDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at news.Dem.main(Dem.java:17) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
>   for [http://localhost:32986/status] to be available after 20002 ms    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188)
>     ... 9 more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Debugging Steps

It may be either of the two below issue.

**1. Chrome Driver not started for some reason:**

Run the chrome driver in terminal maually

**C:\Users\Jim>** `C:\Users\Jim\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe`

Now we have to get the following message denoting server started sucessfully.
[image]

If you are not getting above message and your server is not started, then check what is error you are getting and respond accorsingly? May downloaded corrupted binary, the download it again.

**2. Unable to access the chrome driver with hostname as `localhost`**

If you able to start chromedriver sucessfully as in above steps, now try to access the below url with respective port. 
`http://localhost:{port}/status`

For e.g., in above message, the server started on port 9515. Access the url in browser, `http://localhost:9515/status`

[image]

You should get above message indicating server is accessible with hostname as `localhost`

If your are not able access, then open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in editor with administrator privilege and check `localhost` DNS is mapped to `127.0.0.1`

[image]

Comment: When i try to run it from the terminal it pops an error message saying chromedriver.exe bad image. I believe there is some prob with the installation of chrome

Comment: Yes. Not problem with chrome browser. The downloaded chomedriver.exe should be bad image. Download the binary again.

Comment: yes there was a bad dll. I ran a scan and fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\PATH OF THE DRIVER");
        WebDriver driver = new Chrome driver();
        String url = "https://www.google.com";
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The driver of the path is set correct. that is not the issue