# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for http://localhost:22198/healthz to be available after 20015 ms

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

> Chrome version is: Version 90.0.4430.212
>
> Selenium version is: selenium-java-3.141.59
>
> Chrome driver version is: ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24
>
> Selenium jars are in my project's external libraries.

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class scraper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://google.com";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Output, cut down:

```
May 20, 2021 10:41:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker waitUntilAvailable
INFO: Waiting for http://localhost:22198/healthz
May 20, 2021 10:41:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$1 call
INFO: Polling http://localhost:22198/healthz
Starting ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}) on port 22198
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 20, 2021 10:41:36 AM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$1 call
INFO: Polling http://localhost:22198/healthz
...
May 20, 2021 10:41:54 AM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$1 call
INFO: Polling http://localhost:22198/healthz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for http://localhost:22198/healthz to be available after 20015 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.start(ChromeDriverService.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.execute(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at scraper.main(scraper.java:14)
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening? When I go to http://localhost:22198/healthz in my browser I see:

{"value":{"error":"unknown command","message":"unknown command: unknown command: healthz","stacktrace":"Backtrace:\n\tOrdinal0 [0x0077C013+2474003]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x007129C1+2042305]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00622F68+1060712]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00664B59+1330009]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00604F3F+937791]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00605446+939078]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00605721+939809]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x009096FC+1590332]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x009B8614+2306900]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00809E93+543699]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x008092CE+540686]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x007186BA+2066106]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00604CD0+937168]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00604688+935560]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x009E494C+2487948]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x761EFA29+25]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778E7A7E+286]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778E7A4E+238]\n"}}

If that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821461/selenium-chrome-browser-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waitin

Comment: @cruisepandey unfortunately not, chromedriver starts successfully but seems to have a different issue

Comment: Did you try both of them and nothing worked out  ?

Comment: @cruisepandley Step 1 outputs that starting chromedriver on port 9515 was started successfully and step 2, going to localhost:9515/status I see {"value":{"build":{"version":"90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429})"},"message":"ChromeDriver ready for new sessions.","os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Windows NT","version":"10.0.19042"},"ready":true}}